# Meaning of "Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method" with an interface

Tags: java, interface, access-specifier

I have two files:

```
public interface PrintService {
    void print(PrintDetails details);
    class PrintDetails {
        private String printTemplate;
    }
    public interface Task {
        String ACTION = "print";
    }
}
```

and

```
public class A implements PrintService {
    void print(PrintDetails details) {
        System.out.println("printing: " + details);
    }
    String action = PrintService.Task.ACTION;   
}
```

I thought the code looks okay, but I am getting an error in the second file for the line `void print(PrintDetails details) {` that states:

> Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from `PrintService`.

Can someone explain what this means for me?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In a Java interface each method is by default `public`:

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly abstract, so its body is always represented by a semicolon, not a block.
>
> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public. [[..]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html)

In an implementing class you are not allowed to reduce the visibility, and by not specifying an access modifier:

```
void print(){..}
```

you are specifying the access level [*default*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530065/which-is-the-default-access-specifier-in-java), which has lower visibility than `public`.

Answer (score 3):

Make methode public in the class in which interface implement,because in interface by default every method is public and abstract.