# C#: constructor of nested class makes "inaccessible due to protection level"

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

I have this piece of code, and error is generated, just because I haved added into a constructor for its class.

```
class NestedClass
{
   class A
   {
      A() {}
   }

   class B
   {
       // no constructor
   }

   public static void run()
   {
     A a = new A();  // error
     B b = new B(); // no error
   }
}
```

And error is:

```
NestedExample.A is inaccessible due to protection level
```

Please help me explain this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your constructor as public

```
public A() { }
```

Your constructor for class `A` is **private**

[Private Constructors (C# Programming Guide) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcfb85a6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Note that if you don't use an access modifier with the constructor it
>   will still be **private by default.**

---

The reason it is working for B is that you haven't specified any constructor and for default constructor:

[Constructor - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Unless the class is static, classes without constructors are given a
>   **public default constructor** by the C# compiler in order to enable class instantiation

Answer (score 7):

Your constructor is `private`. Default access modifier for class members is `private`.

```
   class A
   {
      A() {}
   }
```

this is correct implementation

```
   class A
   {
      public A() {}
   }
```

Comment: thanks. I come from java, so I think default for class members is public :D

Comment: @hqt, I think in Java the default is `package`, which is visible inside the package See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530065/which-is-the-default-access-specifier-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Define the constructor as public

```
public class A
{
    public A() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor of A is private. It cannot be accessed from outside of A. 
At the same time, B does not have a consuctor at all and therefore gets a default public constructor.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify, the default  one is private and while in the case of B  the compiler provides a public parameterless constructor for you., so you have to specify it for `class A`

```
class A
{
    public A() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your nested classes `public` and the problem will be solved. Your run method is public but the classes you want to use are not public and this gives problems.

Comment: Indeed you are right about the constructor that just needs to be public. My mistake.