# Why the code is still running after I delete access modifiers in java?

Tags: java

Our lecturer showed us this code yesterday. And I didn't understand why he wrote extra access modifiers. When I delete some parts of code, it is still running.

```
public class Counter {
private final String name;
private int count;

public Counter(String id) {
    name = id;
    count = 0;
}

public void increment() {
    count += 1;
}

public int tally() {
    return count;
}

public String toString() {
    return count + " " + name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Counter c0 = new Counter("first");
    Counter c1 = new Counter("second");

    c0.increment();
    c0.increment();
    c1.increment();

    System.out.println("c0 counter is " + c0);
    System.out.println("c1 counter is " + c1);
}
```

then I delete access modifiers and;

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Counter c0 = new Counter("first");
    Counter c1 = new Counter("second");

    c0.increment();
    c0.increment();
    c1.increment();

    System.out.println("c0 counter is " + c0);
    System.out.println("c1 counter is " + c1);
}
```

the code is still running. Actually I'm not very good at this so can someone tell basically?

Comment: What part of the code you deleted , the private and final keywords ?

Comment: What access modifiers did you delete. Not enough information

Comment: Everything is in one class; `private` is the most *restrictive* access modifier, but that doesn't matter in a program with only one class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the default access specifier in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530065/which-is-the-default-access-specifier-in-java)

Comment: @MickMnemonic It is not a duplicate. It is hardly even related.

Comment: @Gendarme, of course it's related. One of the most confusing things about Java's access modifiers is _package private_ a.k.a "default". Based on the title, that's exactly what the OP is wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Access modifiers control what things *outside* the class can access them. The class itself can access everything.

Answer (score 1):

By removing access modifiers on the class or variables, you are allowing Java to use the default: package access only for classes, public for interfaces.

Since your main is in the same class, it still has access so everything still runs successfully.

For more information:

> Java provides a number of access modifiers to set access levels for classes, variables, methods and constructors. The four access levels are:
>
> Visible to the package. the default. No modifiers are needed.
>
> Visible to the class only (private).
>
> Visible to the world (public).
>
> Visible to the package and all subclasses (protected).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use an access modifier, the method or attribute can be accessed by every class in the same package. I guess your main() is in the same package, that's why it works.

Comment: Not only is it in the same package, but it is in the same class. Access modifiers have no effect what so ever.

Comment: @Gendarme: Yes, probably it is, however th OP seems to have forgotten the closing brace of the class, so you cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are four access modifiers in Java: public, private, protected and package private. When not specified explicitly the visibility is package private by default.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @AndyTurner my understanding was that the OP is asking why it is legal not to specify access modifiers.