# HashMap.Node is not recognised

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I am working on a big project. So, it's not possible to copy the whole code here. But my problem is that by evaluating an expression, I can try the following code and I get `true` back:

```
((HashMap.Node)((HashMap)((FiFiClass)objectTerm.getValue()).getFiFiObjects()).entrySet().toArray()[0]).getKey().equals(FiFiObjectType.AAA)
```

However, when I copy exactly the same code in my code, `Node` is in red color and when I write `HashMap.`, I don't get `Node` as a possible extension of the phrase. Can anyone help me please?

I am using`Java8`.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There is HashMap.Entry, not Node.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I know, but when I try with Entry in the evaluation, I get a typecast error!

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: Can you show us a minimum of your model so we can help you please?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov@YCF_L Thank you both. The problem is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's package-private (more formally known as ["default access"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530065/which-is-the-default-access-specifier-in-java)). That means it's a package implementation detail, and not available to classes outside of the package. See [the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l278).

If you're just trying to get the first key (keeping in mind that [HashMaps aren't ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780541/how-to-sort-a-hashmap-in-java/14936963), so "first" is really "some random key"), then you can just use `keySet().iterator().next()`. And if you're not positive that there is at least one key, you should probably store that Iterator as a local variable, and then call `hasNext()` before you call `next()`.

If you're trying to figure out whether the key set contains `FiFiObjectType.AAA`, then you should just call `... getFiFiObjects().containsKey(FiFiObjectType.AAA)` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. As I have just one element in the HashMap in this specific case, it was also enough to check the first element.

Comment: For completeness, the internal package-private class implements the [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface, which is the element type of the `entrySet()`, in case it’s ever needed (not when you’re interested in the key only). So you also can copy the entry set into a `Map.Entry[]` array or a `List<Map.Entry>`, to get a fixed order for subsequent processing, but it will work much smoother whens not using *raw types*…