# Setting the modifier 'public' in the implementation of an interface method

Tags: java, interface

I know that the following code is wrong because the modifier `public` is missed in the header of the method `m1()` in class `B`. But i wonder "Why?!". Why the code causes a compile error if `public` is missed.

Thanks in advance.

```
interface A{
  void m1();
}
class B implements A{
  void m1(){
    System.out.println("m1");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to have a textual copy of the code, rather than a screenshot. Also, please add an appropriate tag for the language in question.

Comment: @JoeSewell Done

Comment: In interface `A`, the method `m1` is implicitly `public`. But for class `B` method `m1` is implicitly `package-private`. And the compiler won't let you assign weaker access to a method than what the interface allows for. This is a restriction based on the idea of design by contract. If the class can assign weaker access to the method, then the contract advertised by the interface is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default methods have an access of package-private if no access modifier is specified, which means they are public to the package and class only. However interfaces require methods to be implemented by a class using an interface to be public.

[See this stack overflow post for what default access modifiers are for classes and interfaces.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530065/what-is-the-default-access-specifier-in-java)